# LWJGL - Dynamically send VBO data?

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl, vbo

In a voxel game I'm making, I'm using VBO's for rendering the world. I' use somthing like this to send the vertices to the GPU:

```
    FloatBuffer vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(..?);

    float[] vertices = new float[..?];

    //vertex calculations go here

    vertexData.put(vertices);
    vertexData.flip();

    //send the vertices
    int vboVertexHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

However, the vertices are calculated dynamically, and there is no way to know how many I will be rendering beforehand. So I don't know how much space to allocate to the FloatBuffer and to the array.

I thought using ArrayList's but it seems slow and unefficient. Is there any way I can make an array or a FloatBuffer without specifying a size? Or sending the data to the GPU as the vertices are calculated, instead of sending them all in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can make an array or a FloatBuffer without specifying a size?

Why not just use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to generate your data, copy the vertices into a `FloatBuffer`, and then use that?